# An object $S$ is a separator if and only if the set $Mor(A,S)$ is a monosource?

Tags: category-theory

I have started self studying category theory from a set of lecture notes and I am struggling with the following excercise. Let $\mathbb{A}$ be any category.
First I will provide the definitions:

Separator(Dual: Coseparator)

An $\mathbb{A}$-object $S$ is said to be a separator whenever $g,h:A \rightrightarrows B$ are $\mathbb{A}$-morphisms with $g \not= h$, then there is an $\mathbb{A}$-morphism $f: S  \rightarrow A$ such that $hf \not= gf$.

Monosource(Dual: Episink)
Let $A$ be an $\mathbb{A}$-object. A source $(f_{i} : A \rightarrow A_{i})_{I}$ is a class-indexed collection of $\mathbb{A}$-morphisms. A source is called a monosource iff it's left cancellative, i.e: whenever $g,h : B \rightarrow A$ are $\mathbb{A}$-morphisms with $f_{i} g = f_{i} h$ for each $i \in I$, then $g = h$.

So the question goes like this:

An object $S$ is a separator, resp. $C$ a coseparator in $\mathbb{A}$ iff for each $\mathbb{A}$-object $A$, $Mor(A,S)$ is a monosource, resp. $Mor(C,A)$ is an episink in $\mathbb{A}$.

Because of the left cancellation of monosources and for Coseparators there is a morphism $f$ with $fh \not= fg$, it feels that these should go together and similarly for episinks and separators.
Someone please help.

Comment: [The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) pag 172 10.16

Comment: Thanks a lot, figured it out.